# Iterating though JSON Classes

Tags: c#, json

I am a newbie when it comes to this sort of stuff, so here goes:

I am currently working on a COVID-19 Calculator in C# that will model existing data and predict stuff based on that data. I am pulling data from an API endpoint that gives me this .JSON *daily*.

I already managed to get the `CurrentDayStats`, that was the easy part.

I have two questions:

1. How can I iterate through the `HistoricalData` objects without actually defining classes for each and every day. I want to use 2 user inputs so that whenever I give it a certain day in the first input, data about every county could be pulled so that whenever I actually choose a county in the second user input, data will be showed about said county and date.
2. Also, as you can see, each daily class in `HistoricalData` contains `CountyInfectionsNumber` and `Incidence`, classes that have already been defined for `CurrentDayStats`. Can I re-use them? If so, how?

I am also attaching the API classes, and DataModel that I used in order to get to this point.

DataModel (where I define what things should pe pulled from the JSON)

```cs
namespace Licenta
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public int LasUpdatedOn { get; set; }
        public string LasUpdatedOnString { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currentDayStats")]
        public CurrentDayStats data { get; set; }

       // [JsonProperty("historicalData")]
       // public HistoricalData data_zi { get; set; }    
    }

    public class CurrentDayStats
    {
        public int AverageAge { get; set; }
        public int NumberInfected { get; set; }
        public int NumberCured { get; set; }
        public int NumberDeceased { get; set; }
        public float PercentageOfWomen { get; set; }
        public float PercentageOfMen { get; set; }
        public float PercentageOfChildren { get; set; }
        public int NumberTotalDosesAdministered { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("countyInfectionsNumbers")]
        public CountyInfectionsNumbers data2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("incidence")]
        public Incidence data3 { get; set; }
    }

    //this has been commented because I am not sure of it:
    /*
    public class HistoricalData
    {
        [JsonProperty("Day_X")]
        public SelectedDay Zi_Aleasa { get; set; }
    }

    public class SelectedDay
    {
        [JsonProperty("countyInfectionsNumbers")]
        public CountyInfectionsNumbers Ziua_Aleasa2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("incidence")]
        public Incidence Ziua_Aleasa3 { get; set; }
    }
    */ 

    public class CountyInfectionsNumbers
    {
        public int AB { get; set; }
        public int AR { get; set; }
        public int AG { get; set; }
        public int BC { get; set; }
        public int BH { get; set; }
        public int BN { get; set; }
        public int BT { get; set; }
        public int BV { get; set; }
        public int BR { get; set; }
        public int BZ { get; set; }
        public int CS { get; set; }
        public int CL { get; set; }
        public int CJ { get; set; }
        public int CT { get; set; }
        public int CV { get; set; }
        public int DB { get; set; }
        public int DJ { get; set; }
        public int GL { get; set; }
        public int GR { get; set; }
        public int GJ { get; set; }
        public int HR { get; set; }
        public int HD { get; set; }
        public int IL { get; set; }
        public int IS { get; set; }
        public int IF { get; set; }
        public int MM { get; set; }
        public int MH { get; set; }
        public int MS { get; set; }
        public int NT { get; set; }
        public int OT { get; set; }
        public int PH { get; set; }
        public int SM { get; set; }
        public int SJ { get; set; }
        public int SB { get; set; }
        public int SV { get; set; }
        public int TR { get; set; }
        public int TM { get; set; }
        public int TL { get; set; }
        public int VS { get; set; }
        public int VL { get; set; }
        public int VN { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
    }

    public class Incidence
    {
        public float AB { get; set; }
        public float AR { get; set; }
        public float AG { get; set; }
        public float BC { get; set; }
        public float BH { get; set; }
        public float BN { get; set; }
        public float BT { get; set; }
        public float BV { get; set; }
        public float BR { get; set; }
        public float BZ { get; set; }
        public float CS { get; set; }
        public float CL { get; set; }
        public float CJ { get; set; }
        public float CT { get; set; }
        public float CV { get; set; }
        public float DB { get; set; }
        public float DJ { get; set; }
        public float GL { get; set; }
        public float GR { get; set; }
        public float GJ { get; set; }
        public float HR { get; set; }
        public float HD { get; set; }
        public float IL { get; set; }
        public float IS { get; set; }
        public float IF { get; set; }
        public float MM { get; set; }
        public float MH { get; set; }
        public float MS { get; set; }
        public float NT { get; set; }
        public float OT { get; set; }
        public float PH { get; set; }
        public float SM { get; set; }
        public float SJ { get; set; }
        public float SB { get; set; }
        public float SV { get; set; }
        public float TR { get; set; }
        public float TM { get; set; }
        public float TL { get; set; }
        public float VS { get; set; }
        public float VL { get; set; }
        public float VN { get; set; }
        public float B { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

My JSON
[image]

It now says that value cannot be null (json)

```cs
public string json; 
        private void Calc_Atunci_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://datelazi.ro/latestData.json");
            }
            var semiParsedData = JObject.Parse(json);

            const string chosenDate = "2021-01-12";
            const string chosenCountry = "AR";

            var countrySpecificInfections = semiParsedData.SelectToken($"historicalData.{chosenDate}.countyInfectionsNumbers.{chosenCountry}");
            Console.WriteLine(countrySpecificInfections.Value<int>());
        }
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please include the json file (or an excerpt of it) into your question. Please try avoid using pictures to show code or resources.

Comment: Here's the link to the full JSON: "https://datelazi.ro/latestData.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways how can you retrieve those data. Let me show you two similar ways.

#### Test data

Let's suppose you have the data inside `sample.json` then you can load it into a `JObject` to a have a semi parsed version of it.

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
var semiParsedData = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Also let's suppose that you have received the following user inputs for date and country:

```cs
const string chosenDate = "2021-01-12";
const string chosenCountry = "AR";
```

#### via `indexer operator`

```cs
var historicalData = semiParsedData["historicalData"];
var dataOnASpecificDate = historicalData[chosenDate];
var allInfections = dataOnASpecificDate["countyInfectionsNumbers"];
var countrySpecificInfections = allInfections[chosenCountry];
```

Or you can combine all indexer operators into a single statement:

```cs
var countrySpecificInfections = semiParsedData["historicalData"][chosenDate]["countyInfectionsNumbers"][chosenCountry];
```

As you see this is not really neat, that's why I'll show you the `SelectToken` later.

So, if you wish to print out the selected value then you can do that in the following way:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(countrySpecificInfections.Value<int>());
```

#### via `SelectToken`

Instead of using multiple indexer operators you can use a single [jsonPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) to specify the location of the to be retrieved data:

```cs
var countrySpecificInfections = semiParsedData.SelectToken($"historicalData.{chosenDate}.countyInfectionsNumbers.{chosenCountry}");
```

To print out the result you need to call exactly the same statement because in both cases you have retrieved a `JToken`:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(countrySpecificInfections.Value<int>());
```

And the printed output will be `14658`.

---

Obviously this is quite naive implementation and it is quite error-prone. You need to check the queried data's existence on each and every level to make the solution more robust.

Comment: I am having some trouble with semiParsedData but the code is way 100 characters too long to fit in a comment

Comment: @Nistor You can amend your question to include any update. I advice you to append it at the end of your question.

Comment: @Nistor You need to correct this `var json` to `json` and you are ready to go. :D